# Unable to mock class methods using unitest in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

module `a.ClassA`:

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self,callingString):
        print callingString

    def functionInClassA(self,val):
        return val
```

module `b.ClassB`:

```
from a.ClassA import ClassA

class ClassB():
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.value=val

    def functionInsideClassB(self):
        obj=ClassA("Calling From Class B")
        value=obj.functionInClassA(self.value)
```

Python `unittest` class

```
import unittest
from b.ClassB import ClassB
from mock import patch, Mock, PropertyMock,mock

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('b.ClassB.ClassA',autospec = True)
    def _test_sample(self,classAmock):
        dummyMock=Mock()
        dummyMock.functionInClassA.return_value="mocking functionInClassA"
        classAmock.return_value=dummyMock

        obj=ClassB("dummy_val")
        obj.functionInsideClassB()

        assert dummyMock.functionInClassA.assert_called_once_with("dummy_val")
```

The assertion fails. Where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned to `return_value` twice:

```
classAmock.return_value=dummyMock
classAmock.return_value=Mock()
```

That second assignment undoes your work setting up `dummyMock` entirely; the new `Mock` instance has no `functionInClassA` attribute set up.

You don't need to create new mock objects; just use the default `return_value` attribute value:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('b.ClassB.ClassA', autospec=True)
    def test_sample(self, classAmock):
        instance = classAmock.return_value
        instance.functionInClassA.return_value = "mocking functionInClassA"

        obj = ClassB("dummy_val")
        obj.functionInsideClassB()

        instance.functionInClassA.assert_called_once_with("dummy_val")
```

You do **not** need to assert the return value of `assert_called_once_with()` as that is always `None` (making your extra `assert` fail, always). Leave the assertion to the `assert_called_once_with()` method, it'll raise as needed.

Comment: sorry that was  typo, will edit it. Even after the edit its still the same error

Comment: @gully: yes, because you replaced `return_value` twice.

Comment: @Martijin even after the edits the assertion fails,not sure where am I going wrong. Is this the correct way to mock?

Comment: @gully: it should be, if your sample code is correctly reflecting your real code. What does `print(classAmock.mock_calls)` show was accessed on the mock? Do any names match up at all? Put it before the `assert`.

Comment: print(classAmock.calls())  shows 'Mock object has no attribute 'calls' '. The sample code provided is the real code itself

Comment: @gully: sorry, corrected my error, I meant `classAmock.mock_calls`. I'm re-building your case to see what is going on.

Comment: @gully: ah, found the last issue; you are using `assert` on a method that either raises an exception directly or returns `None`.

Comment: @Martijin what would be the correct way to assert then? I assumed that mocking the functionInClassA on dummyMock creates the method internally

Comment: @gully: it does, but you don't need to create a new mock object here. I've added the correct way to assert to my answer; the `assert_called_once_with()` method does the assert itself.

Comment: @Martijin indeed that was the problem 'assert_called_once'  solves it. But what if I also want to test what are the input parameters of the function,how can I test that?

Comment: @gully: you already do so; you tested that the object was called once with the string argument `"dummy_val"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martijin